# How to ask user for contact permission to access then make and open contact?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts

Ok, so I got a contact to go to my phone and it works great except for two things. First, It fails the first time because it asks me for access to the contacts. How can I make it so  it adds it after the user gives access to contacts? Second, Is there a way to open up the contact so the user can view it after it is made? This is what I did :

```
- (IBAction)addContact:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];

    // create person record

    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    // set name and other string values

    NSString *organization = @"American Business Center";
    NSString *personEmail = @"leasing@americanbusinesscenter.com";
    NSString *phoneNo = @"(727)536-6379";
    NSString *webURL = @"www.AmericanBusinessCenter.com";
    NSString *addressOne = @"8340 Ulmerton Road";
    NSString *addressTwo = @"Suite 202";
    NSString *cityName =@ "Largo";
    NSString *stateName = @"Florida";
    NSString *pinCode = @"34209";
    NSString *country = @"United States";

    CFErrorRef cfError=nil;


    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)organization, NULL);

    if (webURL)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef urlMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(urlMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) webURL, kABPersonHomePageLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty, urlMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(urlMultiValue);
    }

    if (personEmail)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) personEmail, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
    }

    if (phoneNo)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        NSArray *venuePhoneNumbers = [phoneNo componentsSeparatedByString:@" or "];
        for (NSString *venuePhoneNumberString in venuePhoneNumbers)
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) venuePhoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }

    // add address

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (addressOne)
    {
        if (addressTwo)
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", addressOne, addressTwo];
        else
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = addressOne;
    }

    if (cityName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey] = cityName;
    if (stateName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey] = stateName;
    if (pinCode)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey] = pinCode;
    if (country)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey] = country;

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
    CFRelease(multiAddress);


    //Add person Object to addressbook Object.
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &cfError);

    if (ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil)) {
        NSLog(@"\nPerson Saved successfuly");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n Error Saving person to AddressBook");
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Based on LML's answer I have done this :

```
- (IBAction)addContact:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];

    // create person record

    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    // set name and other string values

    NSString *organization = @"American Business Center";
    NSString *personEmail = @"leasing@americanbusinesscenter.com";
    NSString *phoneNo = @"(727)536-6379";
    NSString *webURL = @"www.AmericanBusinessCenter.com";
    NSString *addressOne = @"8340 Ulmerton Road";
    NSString *addressTwo = @"Suite 202";
    NSString *cityName =@ "Largo";
    NSString *stateName = @"Florida";
    NSString *pinCode = @"34209";
    NSString *country = @"United States";

    CFErrorRef cfError=nil;


    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)organization, NULL);

    if (webURL)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef urlMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(urlMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) webURL, kABPersonHomePageLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty, urlMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(urlMultiValue);
    }

    if (personEmail)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) personEmail, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
    }

    if (phoneNo)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        NSArray *venuePhoneNumbers = [phoneNo componentsSeparatedByString:@" or "];
        for (NSString *venuePhoneNumberString in venuePhoneNumbers)
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) venuePhoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }

    // add address

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (addressOne)
    {
        if (addressTwo)
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", addressOne, addressTwo];
        else
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = addressOne;
    }

    if (cityName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey] = cityName;
    if (stateName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey] = stateName;
    if (pinCode)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey] = pinCode;
    if (country)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey] = country;

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
    CFRelease(multiAddress);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
            if(error == NULL){
                NSLog(@"Success");
                ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &cfError);
            }
        });
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        CFRelease(person);
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &cfError);
        if(cfError == NULL){
            NSLog(@"Success") ;
        }
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        CFRelease(person);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Adding to address book failed");
    }
}
```

Now, it crashes when I press the button and I am getting the error :

> Passing 'const CFErrorRef *' (aka 'struct __CFError *const *') to parameter of type 'CFErrorRef *' (aka 'struct __CFError **') discards qualifiers

I think I misinterpreted :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!

**To ask permission to access contact, then make and display use the following:**

---

### To ask permission or notify user to allow contacts access :

```
- (IBAction)addContact:(id)sender {
    // Request authorization to Address Book
    ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                [self addContactToAddressBook];
            } else {
                [self customAlert];
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [self addContactToAddressBook];
    }
    else {
        [self customAlert];
    }
}
```

---

### To make contact after permission is accepted :

---

```
- (void)addContactToAddressBook {
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];

    // create person record

    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    // set name and other string values

    NSString *organization = @"American Business Center";
    NSString *personEmail = @"leasing@americanbusinesscenter.com";
    NSString *phoneNo = @"(727)536-6379";
    NSString *webURL = @"www.AmericanBusinessCenter.com";
    NSString *addressOne = @"8340 Ulmerton Road";
    NSString *addressTwo = @"Suite 202";
    NSString *cityName =@ "Largo";
    NSString *stateName = @"Florida";
    NSString *pinCode = @"34209";
    NSString *country = @"United States";

    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)organization, NULL);

    if (webURL)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef urlMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(urlMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) webURL, kABPersonHomePageLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty, urlMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(urlMultiValue);
    }

    if (personEmail)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) personEmail, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
    }

    if (phoneNo)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        NSArray *venuePhoneNumbers = [phoneNo componentsSeparatedByString:@" or "];
        for (NSString *venuePhoneNumberString in venuePhoneNumbers)
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) venuePhoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }

    // add address

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (addressOne)
    {
        if (addressTwo)
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", addressOne, addressTwo];
        else
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = addressOne;
    }

    if (cityName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey] = cityName;
    if (stateName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey] = stateName;
    if (pinCode)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey] = pinCode;
    if (country)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey] = country;

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, &error);
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
```

### Then open new contact

```
    ABPersonViewController *ctrl = [[ABPersonViewController alloc]init];

    ctrl.allowsEditing = NO;
    [ctrl setPersonViewDelegate:self];
    [ctrl setDisplayedPerson:person];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UILabel * titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    titleView.text = @"Info";
    titleView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ctrl.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
    [titleView sizeToFit];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

```
   - (IBAction)addContact:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker=[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = [peoplePicker addressBook];

    // create person record

    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();
    // set name and other string values

    NSString *organization = @"American Business Center";
    NSString *personEmail = @"leasing@americanbusinesscenter.com";
    NSString *phoneNo = @"(727)536-6379";
    NSString *webURL = @"www.AmericanBusinessCenter.com";
    NSString *addressOne = @"8340 Ulmerton Road";
    NSString *addressTwo = @"Suite 202";
    NSString *cityName =@ "Largo";
    NSString *stateName = @"Florida";
    NSString *pinCode = @"34209";
    NSString *country = @"United States";

    CFErrorRef error=nil;


    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef)organization, NULL);

    if (webURL)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef urlMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(urlMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) webURL, kABPersonHomePageLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty, urlMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(urlMultiValue);
    }

    if (personEmail)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(emailMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) personEmail, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, emailMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
    }

    if (phoneNo)
    {
        ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
        NSArray *venuePhoneNumbers = [phoneNo componentsSeparatedByString:@" or "];
        for (NSString *venuePhoneNumberString in venuePhoneNumbers)
            ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFStringRef) venuePhoneNumberString, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
        ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
        CFRelease(phoneNumberMultiValue);
    }

    // add address

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (addressOne)
    {
        if (addressTwo)
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", addressOne, addressTwo];
        else
            addressDictionary[(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey] = addressOne;
    }

    if (cityName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey] = cityName;
    if (stateName)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey] = stateName;
    if (pinCode)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey] = pinCode;
    if (country)
        addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey] = country;

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) addressDictionary, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
    CFRelease(multiAddress);


    //Add person Object to addressbook Object.
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
            if(error == NULL){
                NSLog(@"Success");
            }
        });
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        CFRelease(person);
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
        if(error == NULL){
            NSLog(@"Success") ;
        }
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        CFRelease(person);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Adding to address book failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Crashes the app... I did find out that it was after the "Second Success" that it did it

Comment: please paste the crash log

Comment: Thats the weird thing, it just says lldb

Comment: Thanks, @LML, Got it working using a different method, however, how can i show the new contact?